# What is the best way to add a permanent route?

Tags: debian, centos, rhel, route

I need to add a route that won't be deleted after reboot. I read these two ways of doing it :

> Add  `ip route add -net 172.X.X.0/24 gw 172.X.X.X dev ethX` to the file  `/etc/network/interfaces`

or

> Create the file **/etc/network/if-up.d/route** with:

```
#!/bin/sh
route add -net 172.X.X.0/24 gw 172.X.X.X dev ethX
```

and make it executable :

```
chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/route
```

So I'm confused. What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: looks like you're focused on a Linux system? (we have AIX, HPUX, Irix, Solaris, ....) on the site.

Comment: You are right sorry I didn't specify that it was on a linux Debian system. Thanks for reminding it to me.

Comment: You should use iproute2 commands like `ip route add <network> via <IP> dev <DEV>` instead of [net-tools](https://lwn.net/Articles/710533/) commands (ifconfig, route etc.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You mentioned `/etc/network/interfaces`, so it's a Debian system...

Create a named routing table. As an example, I have used the name,  "mgmt," below.

```
echo '200 mgmt' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Above, the kernel supports many routing tables and refers to these by unique integers numbered 0-255. A name, mgmt, is also defined for the table.

Below, a look at a default `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` follows, showing that some numbers are reserved. The choice in this answer of 200 is arbitrary; one might use any number that is not already in use, 1-252.

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
```

Below, a Debian 7/8 interfaces file defines `eth0` and `eth1`. `eth1` is the 172 network. `eth0` could use DHCP as well. `172.16.100.10` is the IP address to assign to `eth1`. `172.16.100.1` is the IP address of the router.

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The production network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
# iface eth0 inet dhcp 
# Remove the stanzas below if using DHCP.
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.10.10.140
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.10.10.1

# The management network interface
auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 172.16.100.10
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  post-up ip route add 172.16.100.0/24 dev eth1 src 172.16.100.10 table mgmt
  post-up ip route add default via 172.16.100.1 dev eth1 table mgmt
  post-up ip rule add from 172.16.100.10/32 table mgmt
  post-up ip rule add to 172.16.100.10/32 table mgmt
```

Reboot or restart networking.

**Update - Expounding on EL**

I noticed in a comment that you were "wondering for RHEL as well."
In Enterprise Linux ("EL" - RHEL/CentOS/et al), create a named routing table as mentioned, above.

The EL `/etc/sysconfig/network` file:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=host.sld.tld
GATEWAY=10.10.10.1
```

The EL `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file, using a static configuration (without NetworkManager and not specifying "HWADDR" and "UUID" for the example, below) follows.

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTOCOL=none
IPADDR=10.10.10.140
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=10.10.10.0
BROADCAST=10.10.10.255
```

THE EL `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` file (without NetworkManager and not specifying "HWADDR" and "UUID" for the example, below) follows.

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTOCOL=none
IPADDR=172.16.100.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=172.16.100.0
BROADCAST=172.16.100.255
```

The EL `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` file:

```
172.16.100.0/24 dev eth1 table mgmt
default via 172.16.100.1 dev eth1 table mgmt
```

The EL `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1` file:

```
from 172.16.100.0/24 lookup mgmt
```

### Update for RHEL8

This method described above works with RHEL 6 & RHEL 7 as well as the derivatives, but for RHEL 8 and derivatives, one must first install `network-scripts` to use the method described above.

```
dnf install network-scripts
```

The installation produces a warning that `network-scripts` will be removed in one of the next major releases of RHEL and that NetworkManager provides `ifup`/`ifdown` scripts as well.

Comment: For the Debian approach, you likely need to add equivalent `pre-down` or `post-down` commands to clean up the routes when the interface is taken down, otherwise a `systemctl restart networking` will error out when it tries to add an existing route for the interface.

Answer (score -1):

On Debian based distro you can add a static route permanently as follows:

```
 echo "up route add -net 172.X.X.X/24 gw 172.X.X.X dev ethX" | sudo tee --append /etc/network/interfaces
```

On RHEL based distro:

```
echo "172.X.X.X/24 via 172.X.X.X" | sudo tee --append /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX
```

Comment: The `sudo` is meaningless in both your two commands. Either you're already root, so the `>>` works, or you're not, in which case the `>>` is applied as your original user and only the `echo` is run as root. Also, this fails dismally if there are multiple interfaces defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: echo "sth" | sudo tee filename

Comment: this is not working for debian instances in gcp

Comment: Indeed, concerning the Debian version, the given command highly depends on what interface is configured last in the file /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Any scripts in Debian should now use iproute2 commands like `ip route add <network> via <IP> dev <DEV>` instead of net-tools route and ifconfig commands that are not installed by default.

Comment: @AdamKalisz As you can see this answer is posted 4 years ago.