# Is rc.local the best place to add a pon start and network routing change?

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi, dhcp, route

I've followed [this guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/getting-started-super-sim-raspberry-pi-waveshare-4g-hat#software-setup) to get a 4G hat networked with my pi zero, and everything seems fine. I'm able to ping out once `pon` has started in the background and a route has been added.

What I want is for the pi to boot and for `pon` to be running already, and the route to be already added.

I'm currently doing this in the `rc.local` file, but I'm pretty sure it's quite a dirty approach:

```
sleep 20
sudo pon &
sleep 20
sudo route add -net "0.0.0.0" ppp0

exit 0
```

Ultimately, I want to be sure that the network is up on the newly defined `ppp0` route before executing any python.

I've had a look at [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321687/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-permanent-route) but unsure of the correct approach: could this be done with `pre-up.d` or some kind of interfaces change?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the raspberry pi OS you're using support systemd?

Comment: @JonathanHeady it does!

Comment: Probably roll back your edit and add the answer as a, well, answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

How I did it was to create x2 systemd services and a change to the routing table.

1. `4gpon.service` used to start pon in the background:

```
[Unit]
Description=4G hat networing

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/poff
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Updating the routing table to enable ppp0 by default

```
sudo ip route delete default
sudo ip route add default dev ppp0
```

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/ppp0

# add:
auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet provider
up ip route add default dev ppp0
```

Then in addition [to the values defined here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/getting-started-super-sim-raspberry-pi-waveshare-4g-hat#4-connect-to-the-internet) for this file, add this one too:

```
sudo nano /etc/ppp/peers/provider

# add at bottom:
replacedefaultroute
```

3. The `garage-motion.service` that calls the python upon knowing the first service is up

```
[Unit]
Description=Motion detector service
After=network.target network-online.target 4gpon.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=***your-region***"
Environment="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***your-key***"
Environment="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***your-secret-key***"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/pi/projects/garage-motion/venv/python3 /home/pi/projects/garage-motion/venv/garage-motion.ph --serve-in-foreground'
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script that executes on startup via systemd.

First create a script for the commands. Ensure that it has execution permissions.

Next create a service file in `/etc/systemd/system` with a filename that ends with `.service` and containing the following sections:

```
[Unit]
Description=Description of script/service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash [path to script]

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then reload the systemctl daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Finally, install the script using systemctl, with the filename as the `servicename`:

```
systemctl enable --now [servicename]
```

Related:

- [Cause a script to execute after networking has started?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started)
- https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019672

Comment: So I'm thinking that this will need x3 services? x1 for pon, x1 for the route add after pon has started, and then the final for the python that has to be ran when the connection is up? I have amended my question with a work in progress. What do you think?

Comment: @HarryLincoln I didn't realize you could add the commands directly into the ExecStart Looks pretty good. Only thing I can see that may be problematic is the space between `/usr/bin` and `source` in the third service. Not sure if the path is needed since source is an internal command. Shouldn't hurt to try it though. Provided the Pi can be rebooted for testing without interrupting production usage.

Comment: Yeah, that should be something like `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c ' source /home/you/projects/bike-shed/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/you/do-the-thing.py'` but in practice you can probably simplify to just `ExecStart=/home/you/projects/bike-shed/venv/bin/python3 /home/you/do-the-thing.py`. Notice that `systemd` runs as `root` so `~` would expand to `/root`, not your own home directory.

Comment: (Properly speaking, system scripts should be owned by `root` and stored in a system location like `/usr/local/bin` or perhaps e.g. `/usr/local/lib`)